# Ordering MySQL Full Text Search results they have the identical scores

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I am using MySQL Full Text Search to try and find all results for the word `lane` like this..

```
    SELECT *
        MATCH (title) AGAINST ('lane') AS score
    FROM
        `books`
    WHERE
        MATCH (title) AGAINST ('lane') AS score
    ORDER
        BY score DESC
```

This is working and returning expected results, the problem is that they all have an equal score so they appear randomly in the results. I would like to sort them by first appearance, something like this...

```
Red Lane
Lanes
Search For Hidden Lane
House On The Lane
Lane Of The Day
```

Would turn into..

```
Lanes
Lane Of The Day
Red Lane
House On The Lane
Search For Hidden Lane
```

Or something similar, do I have any other options on ordering when they all return the same score?

Comment: You can add additional ordering criteria, e.g. alphabetical. `ORDER BY score, title`

Answer (score 1):

For your text you can use the Position if Lane in the text, but i still wonder how you got Lanes as result

```
    SELECT *,
        MATCH (title) AGAINST ('lane' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score
    FROM
        `books`
    WHERE
        MATCH (title) AGAINST ('lane'IN BOOLEAN MODE) >0
    ORDER
        BY score DESC,POSITION('lane' IN  title)
```

| title | score |
| --- | --- |
| Lane Of The Day | 0.009391550906002522 |
| Red Lane | 0.009391550906002522 |
| House On The Lane | 0.009391550906002522 |
| Search For Hidden Lane | 0.009391550906002522 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dXXW9I6g)